# dynamic rendering compilation of vue2 templates with components embedded

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I hope somebody can help me with my vue.js question regarding version 2.6.14

I created a component "dynamiccontent" capable of displaying html string generated from a backend api (with vue variables/functions in). the component utilizes vue.compile and render functions. it works great for the test case "slide working" in the app when I use my code for normal html tags.

here is the test function

```
Vue.component("test-slide", {
  template:
    '<div :key="slide.id"><dynamiccontent v-bind:slide="slide"></dynamiccontent></div>',
  props: ["slide"]
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#player",
  template:
    "<div>working: <test-slide v-bind:slide='slideworking'></test-slide><br> problem: <test-slide v-bind:slide='slidenotworking'></test-slide></div>",
  methods: {
    test() {
      return "test";
    }
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      slideworking: {
        id: "dkd",
        content:
          "<div>test {{this.getDynamic()}}<div><div>test {{this.getDynamic()}}<div>test {{this.getDynamic()}}</div></div></div></div>"
      },
      slidenotworking: {
        id: "dkd",
        content:
          "<div>test {{this.getDynamic()}}<test-component>{{this.getDynamic()}}<test-component>test {{this.getDynamic()}}<test-component>test {{this.getDynamic()}}</test-component></test-component></test-component></div>"
      }
    };
  }
});
```

as soon es I try to use variables in cascaded components (see the sample data "slide notworking", which uses vue components as well, in this example testcomponent) the compile function seems to ignore all the Childs.

#### The Problem as a codepen with the demo source

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/martinbe1io/pen/NWaQavq)

#### What is expected?

vue.compile should compile the child components as well

#### What is actually happening?

vue compile seems to stop at the first vue component